# How to add type / interface to function() declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have types like this defined in a separate file:

```
type AddFunc = (a: number, b:number) => number
```

and am using them to type "fat arrow" functions:

```
const add: AddFunc = (a, b) => a + b
```

This is fine, however I came across an issue when changing above to a function declaration i.e

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

I'm not sure, but is there a way to re-use `AddFunc` type for above?The only approach I figured out is to do it manually like below, but I wonder if I can reuse existing types instead

```
function add(a: number, b: number): number {
   return a + b
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...I wonder if I can reuse existing types instead

Sadly, not really. I mean, you *could* do something like this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAYgVwHYGMoF4oAoCGAXFKsgLYBGEATgDRQWGmU0CU2AfCeVdQFB8AZmnTAAlgHtUUfAlwA6RfmoBzAM7EACsvxkIwGmoA88JCI6tiAJX3JqqACrgIJhCgxcA3nyi+o6KTVgKABtfHoKAF1sGVU1AG4fP2pbexkoAGoGRIBfIA)):

```typescript
function add(...args: Parameters<AddFunc>): ReturnType<AddFunc> {
    const [a, b] = args;
    return a + b;
}
```

...but while that means you only have to update one place (`AddFunc`) if doing this with multiple functions of the same type, it's hardly concise. :-)

It does offer good IDE auto-complete etc., though, thanks to the `Parameters` tuple type:

[image: Screenshot showing TypeScript playground with call to add with the cursor just after the opening ( showing the playground prompting the user with the a and b parameters and their types]